# I got stuck on a Step of TestCase. Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate a test case using Selenium WebDriver in java, but I got stuck on one step. I need to locate an element and click on it. I tried to locate it by id, by class, by csselector, by licktext... but it didn´t work.

This is what I did:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href=http://mucs70064.corp.knorr-bremse.com:1080/Windchill/app/#ptc1/site/listUtilities?oid=OR%3Awt.inf.container.ExchangeContainer%3A5&u8=1]")).click();    
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[ext\\:tree-node-id*='site'][ext\\:tree-node-id*='listUtilities'] a")).click();    
driver.findElement(By.className("x-tree-node-anchor")).click();    
driver.findElement(By.className("x-tree-node-indent")).click();
```

Unfortunately no one of the statement above worked. Does anybody knows how can I proceed? I made a photo of what my Browser´s developer tools shows, but since I don´t have yet enough reputation to upload it, you can see the image in the following link.

[enter link description here](http://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo?album_id=3353372615&photo_id=20717596341#20717596341)

I would really appreciate any help!

Regards
Thanks a lot
Pablo

Comment: Can you post the HTML code? What error are you getting?

Comment: I am not getting an error. It is just that after running part of the testcase without problems I reach a step where the program  is unable to find the element that should click.
I uploaded a photo with the information that shows the developer tools when I point the element .
You find this photo in the link that I posted

Comment: Your link says "You cannot access this album"

Comment: Ok, I upload again in a different hosting.
http://www.m-i-u.de/display-i93958bs0bgl.html

I think it works now

Comment: @pablocasanovas: Does the value of the attribute unselectable ever change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel this might be because the `unselectable` attribute's value is `on`. You can wait until the value of the attribute changes. Other attribute I saw was `hidefocus=on`.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);

wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                         WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath"));
                         String enabled = button.getAttribute("unselectable");
                         if(enabled.equals("off")) 
                            return true;
                         else
                            return false;
                    }
});
```

**Edit**:

Get all the links and then click on the last one.

```
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.className("x-tree-node-anchor"));
links.get(links.size()-1); //this will give you the last link
```

Comment: The thing is that I have a list of elements like it is shown in this image
http://www.m-i-u.de/display-i93962bnbgp5.html

I have to select the last element (Diensprogramme).

The HTML code contains of course the information of every element. I show you the information of the last 2 elements (mine is the one which is red marked).

http://www.m-i-u.de/display-i93961bxgflz.html

So as shown every elements have an "unselectable" or "hidefocus"
I think it didn´t work because of that.

Comment: Have you tried `linkText`? If not that then, try getting a list of all the links. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thnaks a lot for your answer. I am getting now an error when I try to get all the links.
The error says: the type list is not eneric, it cannot be parametriced with arguments <webElement>

Comment: @pablocasanovas:  Ok I just quickly googled that error, found out your import should be `java.util.List`.

Comment: One question more. How would it be if the element is not the last one of the list. Imagine that I have a list of 15 elements and I want to click on the element number 6? Would it be something like links.get(links.size(6)).click()  ?

Comment: It says that the method size is not applicant for the argument(int) so I guess I have to pass the index in another way.

I feel like an idiot asking this but how can I mark this solution as accepted?

Comment: Hi again. That it is really confusing. It doesn´t work anymore, but I haven´t change anything! How is that possible? Exactly the same code..

Comment: Check the html source to see if the link is actually there or not.

Comment: maybe should I remove the content of the list after making click on my desired element?. Maybe I am getting problems because the list is not empty when I run the program again. Can it the the reason?

Comment: No, I don't think that the list content is creating any problems. See if you are getting any exceptions, check if the link is present and add some explicit wait for the link to be clickable.

Comment: you are amazing LittlePanda. It was the time!. IT wasn´t enough to load. It works fine now. Thanks a lot

Comment: One last question please, in the next step I find something similar. The image is here http://www.m-i-u.de/display-i94045b6wkwq.html
Theoretically I could do this   List<WebElement> links_2 = driver.findElements(By.className("title"));
  links_2.get(9).click();  right?
In this case I write there 9, because the element is the number 10 in the list. But it doesn´t work.